# Wrong variable when looping all element in nodelist

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, getelementsbytagname

I create a nodelist that selects 2 divs. Then I create a function to show the index of the div that the user clicks. But the output is always be 2. I don't figure out where the mistake is.

This is just a simple problem, but it will solve my other complex problems with many events inside events. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div style="background:red; height:50px"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:50px"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    div[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vutienphat/tm279uot/

Comment: that's kind of an odd way to set functions on your divs.  Won't the code have looped all the way through the set of divs before a user ever clicks?  (meaning the number of divs on the page will always be the alert, instead of the index of the div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> In your case, value of `i` is nothing but a value `i` has at the end of the loop which is `length-1` of node list.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].onclick = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      alert(i);
    }
  })(i)
}
```

```html
<div style="background:red; height:50px"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:50px"></div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tm279uot/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The output is always 2 because you are alerting the increment variable which has already ended by the time someone clicks. Consider the following code logic instead

```js
function index(element) {
    for ( var i = 0; element = element.previousElementSibling; i++ );
    return i;
}

divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(index(this));
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="background:red; height:50px"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:50px"></div>
```